# Several unknown estimates from many equations

Tags: python, equation

I have thousands of Bill of Materials in SQL database and I know the working hours of the jobs.

I would like to estimate the installation time required for a particular part.
Of course, working hours are not always proportionate.

Simply put, it should be calculated from similar equations.

```
a+2b+c+5d+e = 200
b+3c+d+6e+f = 250
a+4c+d+7e+f = 300
...
a=?
b=?
c=?
...
```

What method and framework could I use to do this?

Comment: [mcve] is great start when asking SQL questions.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: The SQL queries is not problem. 
I checked the Numpy and Sympy, but these only calculate exact values.
Working hours may vary from time to time.

Comment: I think you want [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). But your example system of equations has 6 unknown variables but only three equations. So there are infinite solutions.

Comment: @bb1950328
I have 4981 equations and hundreds of unknowns. Thans for your information. 
I think Gaussian elimination would be great if the value of the unknowns didn’t change.
I tried Simpy linear equation solver but the solution requires constant values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a standard problem.  You can treat your data as points in a multidimensional space—(1,2,1,5,1,0,…,200), (0,1,3,1,6,1,…,250), and (1,0,4,1,7,1,…,300) for your example—and seek a **least-squares** fit for the functional form *ax*+*by*+*cz*+…=*h* to estimate *a*, *b*, *etc.*

Numpy of course [supports this](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.lstsq.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it looks good at first. I have yet to find out if it really works, but our answer is useful.